# The projection of $v_1$ onto $W$ is $Proj_wv$. Why the projection of $v_1$ onto the orthogonal complement of $W$ is $v_1−Proj_wv_1$?

Tags: linear-algebra

At first i attempted to find the projection for the orthogonal complement in the same way i found $Proj_wv$, meaning find the projection of $v_1$ onto each basis vector of $W$ and add them.

But i saw that the solution is $v_1 − Proj_wv_1$. Why is this the case? Looking for some intuition, not rigorous proof

Answer (score 1):

For $W$, you found the projection onto each basis vector and added the results together.

The same works for the orthogonal complement, say $W^\prime$. However, the trick is to realise that the direct sum of $W$ and $W^\prime$ is the whole vector space (assuming the inner product space is complete), i.e. the union of the basis of $W$ and the basis of $W^\prime$ is a basis for the whole space.

Thus, $Proj_W(v) + Proj_{W^\prime}(v) = v$. Rearranging then gives the result you're looking for, $Proj_{W^\prime}(v) = v - Proj_W(v)$.